# Is windows command line prompt similar to o/s interpreter?

Tags: cmd, operating-system, command, interpreter, prompt

Is windows command line prompt similar to o/s interpreter? that mean o/s interpreter is command interpreter. command interpreter Is cmd also the interface of the command interpreter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. OS/2 is the same as Win NT 4 CMD.exe. In Windows 2000 it was upgraded and this is the current feature version. All references in help to new behaviour is the differences between OS/2-NT4 and Windows 2000.

CMD.exe was written by a IBM engineer. She added scripting features common on IBM mainframes to the MSDos Command.com for the OS/2 shell.

Microsoft had rights to OS/2 as IBM had rights to Windows 3.11. OS/2 included a full copy of Windows 3.11 and Windows NT included a full copy of OS/2. NB. All MSDos commands work as they would in command.com in CMD.exe.

Also while OS/2 was included in Windows NT MSDos programs would run in the OS/2 subsystem Dos emulator rather that the Win NT subsystem Dos emulator.

Windows NT family are Win NT 3.1, 3.51, 4, Windows 2000, XP, Vista, 7, 8, and 10. Windows NT is an operating system that runs other operating systems. It runs now or in the past - OS/2 V2, MSDos 5.5, Posix, various Unixs, Linux, Win 16 bit, Win 32 bit, Win 64 bit.

PS In Win32 32 bit Windows OS is implemented by CSRSS (Client Server Runtime Sub System) and 16 bit programs run in the NTVDM emulator (a 32 bit program that run MSDos and Win 16). In 64 bit programs 64 bit Windows is implemented by CSRSS.exe (a native NT executable not Windows).

Further reading:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture_of_Windows_NT

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API

https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-windows7-vista64-support-32bit-applications.htm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS/2