# Batch - Sending Standard Error/Output with Shift and Looping

Tags: batch-file, cmd, standard-error, redirectstandardoutput, nul

I need help with some batch. We are not allowed to use if errorlevel statements yet or anything advanced, we are just in an introductory phase and the first couple weeks of class. Just using standard error/output, stuff like that. I am bit stuck on the user verification part and sending it to nul.I realize I used a ghetto way of hiding the date and computer name but if you have a better way please suggest.

Here is the assignment

[image]

Here is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF

:: hide date and computer name from echoing when no paramater entered
IF "%1"=="" GOTO :NOPARAM

:: Display date and computer name
echo.
echo On %date%, on %computername%
echo.

:USER
::end batch file if no value for %1
IF "%1"=="" GOTO :EOF
echo %1
net user %1 | find /i "Full Name"
net user %1 | find /i "Password last set" 
echo.
SHIFT
GOTO USER

:: Display error message if user attempts to run batch file without entering a parameter
:NOPARAM
echo You did not enter a parameter! Please try again with a parameter.
GOTO :EOF

:: Display error message if user does not exist.
:NOEXISTENCE
echo The %1 user does not exist.
```

Comment: One good start is to use `REM` as the comment character. `::` is a malformed label and not a comment. It will crash your programs when you start using other language elements in the future.

Comment: The purpose of `shift` is to allow a batch file to handle more than 9 command line parameters.

Comment: Yes I understand the purpose of shift. I am stuck on if the user does not exist, display an error message. I will use REM from now on.

Comment: You can use conditional execution if you cannot use the `IF` command.  A double pipe, `II` means execute the next command if the previous command was not successful.  A double ampersand `&&` means execute the next command if the previous command was successful.

Comment: I am not sure where I would put that logic in my script, that is what I am stuck on.

Comment: `(net user "Mr User" 2>nul) && Echo Sucess || Echo Fail`. Which is the same as 3 lines `net user "Mr User" 2>nul` and `if errorlevel 1 Echo Fail` and `if not errorlevel 1 echo Success`.

Comment: See CMD Cheat Sheet https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/command-prompt-cheat-sheet.html

Comment: How would I encorporate this while also piping find so I can display their full name and password last set if they do exist? Anything I try adding after | find /i seems to not work.

Comment: You would do it twice. Once, hiding the output, to see if the name exists. then to get what you want if it does. This is a bullshit assignment. You are learning how NOT to program batch. With programming tools you go with the flow. Batch batches user commands so they don't have to type multiple things to start a program.

Comment: We can use IF EXIST and IF NOT EXIST statements in this assignment if that can help better but no else or anything.

If the name does not exist then we need to GOTO NOEXISTENCE, echo the user does not exist, and then shift back to USER and keep searching. If the name DOES exist then we need to display only their full name and password last set via net user via a find pipe.

I have net user "%1" 2>nul || GOTO NOEXISTENCE

Comment: When executing userinfo steez jon bob dan

it will display:

steez
"The steez user does not exist"

and then all the info from net user about jon, bob, and dan because they exist. I need that not to happen so we can do the find.. This is the code I have now: https://pastebin.com/UA9m1mLi

Comment: It seems > nul 2>&1 || GOTO NOEXISTENCE did the job. I am going to double check everything.

Comment: The normal way to handle this programming problem in batch is to use a `for` loop (and indeed most languages), but your assignment doesn't allow that.

Comment: See this answer for background https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462602/is-windows-command-line-prompt-similar-to-o-s-interpreter/60462887#60462887.

Comment: I'm surprised that you apparently are allowed to use `&&` and `||` (seen in your linked code) considering, `if errorlevel` is not allowed. Anyhow - to fulfill the assignment as written, you'll need one of those methods (except I'm "too advanced" to remember the "basics").